# Making a camera in a 2D game (glOrtho)

Tags: opengl, java

I'm trying to make a camera that follows my character and it seems I've managed. However, I don't know how to limit that my camera don't follow me when my character reachs the boundaries of the windows (it's ugly see black spaces beyond my tile map x_x).

So, this is my code:

```
public class Camera {
    public void update(Vector2f spritePos) {
        Vector2f pos = new Vector2f(spritePos.getX()-368, spritePos.getY()-268);

        if((pos.getX()+368 > 368) && (pos.getY()+268 > 268)) {
                glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(pos.getX(), 
                pos.getX() + Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth(), 
                pos.getY() + Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight(), 
                pos.getY(), 
                -1, 
                1);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        }
    }
}
```

I substract 368 to the X position, because I want to place my character at the center of my camera. Same with 268. This is a bad way to archieve this, because my camera "jumps" roughly to the position of my character >.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's problem for you? just put limits on the values you pass to the glOrtho function.

Comment: The problem is, that if I reach a left limit of the screen the camera stop moving. Ok, that's fine, but it doesn't move upwards :/ And when I recover the camera again, it jumps to the character causing an ugly effect...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the if condition

```
(pos.getX()+368 > 368) is equal to (pos.getX() > 0)  and
(pos.getY()+268 > 268) is equal to (pos.getY() > 0)
```

then the refactored condition can be

```
 if( ( pos.getX() > 0 ) && ( pos.getY() > 0 ) ) 
 //that means that the camera is only updated if pos is > that 0,0
```

For example, if pos is -2,0 the condition is false and the camera is not updated.
We want that camera follow the character included in this case

then

```
public void update(Vector2f spritePos) {
Vector2f pos = new Vector2f(spritePos.getX()-368, spritePos.getY()-268);

// new code
float cameraPosX = 0;
float cameraPosY = 0;

cameraPosX = ( pos.getX() < 0 ) ? 0 : pos.getX();
cameraPosY = ( pos.getY() < 0 ) ? 0 : pos.getY();
//

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(cameraPosX, 
            cameraPosX + Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth(), 
            cameraPosY + Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight(), 
            cameraPosY, 
            -1, 
            1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}
```

this code always update the camera, but clamps the camera position in x and/or y

Comment: Thank you very much!! Seriously I had getting mad with this >.<U I have tested your code and works perfect. Now I only have to limit the right and down boundaries, but that's easy with your example. Thank you again =D